# Error: The 'pycuda' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, pycuda

What is causing this error?

```
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pycuda' distribution was not found and is required by the application
-------------------------------------------------------------------
PyCUDA ERROR: The context stack was not empty upon module cleanup.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
A context was still active when the context stack was being
cleaned up. At this point in our execution, CUDA may already
have been deinitialized, so there is no way we can finish
cleanly. The program will be aborted now.
Use Context.pop() to avoid this problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. The code you're trying to run wants to use the `pycuda` package, but the package is not installed.

You can try running `pip install pycuda`, preferably inside a virtuaenv.